Bokeh: OpenDialog triggered from Dropdown
Bokeh 3.6.0
Working with Bokeh server, I try to open a bokeh.models.Dialog model. Usually, this is done via my_button.js_on_click(OpenDialog(Dialog=dialog))
Now, I'm struggling to open a given dialog depending on Dropdown model. Here is a minimal example:
from bokeh.models import (
    Div,
    CustomJS,
    Dropdown,
    Dialog,
    OpenDialog,
    CloseDialog,
)
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc

d1 = Dialog(title="Dialog 1", content=Div(text="<h1>Dialog 1</h1>"))
d2 = Dialog(title="Dialog 2", content=Div(text="<h1>Dialog 2</h1>"))

menu = Dropdown(label="Test", menu=["option1", "option2"])

# This works, but always open the same Dialog...
# menu.js_on_click(OpenDialog(dialog=d1))

# This is what I would like...
menu.js_on_click(
    {menu.menu[0]: OpenDialog(dialog=d1), menu.menu[1]: OpenDialog(dialog=d2)}
)

curdoc().add_root(menu)


Credits goes to https://discourse.bokeh.org/u/gmerritt123
The OpenDialog() object has an execute() method:
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import (
    Div,
    CustomJS,
    Dropdown,
    Dialog,
    OpenDialog,
    CloseDialog,
)
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc

d1 = Dialog(title="Dialog 1", content=Div(text="<h1>Dialog 1</h1>"))
d2 = Dialog(title="Dialog 2", content=Div(text="<h1>Dialog 2</h1>"))
# open randomly one of dialog boxes. 
# `dialog` to be overwritten later in JS code
open_dialog = OpenDialog(dialog=d1)

menu = Dropdown(label="Test", menu=["option1", "option2"])

trigger_dialog = CustomJS(
    args=dict(d1=d1, d2=d2, d=open_dialog),
    code="""
    if (this.item == 'option1') {
        d.dialog = d1
    } else if (this.item == 'option2'){
        d.dialog = d2
    };

    d.execute()
    """,
)
menu.js_on_click(trigger_dialog)

curdoc().add_root(menu)

